# How do i remove unwanted spaces from exported XML data being loaded into javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I've seen similar questions and answers to what i need, But my spaces are in a different place to the other questions i've seen.

I am exporting data from the employee database into an XML file which is then loaded into HTML via javascript.

Below is an example slice of how the XML data is retrieved from the employee database.

```
<employee>
     <id>2552      </id>
     <name>BOBBY                LEE              </name>
     <team>BOB  </team>
     <datein>      78130</datein>
     <timein> 055541    </timein>
     <dateout>     78129</dateout> 
     <timeout> 140128</timeout>
      <active>Yes</active>
</employee>
```

As you can see there are spaces in the extracted data. I am using the employee id to pull an image file. So for this employee i would use the id (2552      ) Though as it has 6 spaces i cannot call the image file (2552      .png) as that won't work.

Is there a way i can remove the 6 spaces so that i can load a file called 2552.png?

Thanks.

EDIT #1

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    document.write("<table border='0'>");
    document.write("<tr><td id=pic><img src=../images/employees/");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write(".png width=100 height=100></td><td id=Yes>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

That is the code i use to pull information from the XML file.

EDIT #2

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "DATA.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

XML load code, which is stored in the header.

Comment: remove the spaces before converting into XML

Comment: With the system i'm using (ProIV) it's not possible to do it before exporting - so i need a way to do it after exporting.

Comment: what do you mean loaded into Javascript?  For display or logic?

Comment: It's loaded into javascript and displayed in tables on a basic HTML page which allows the Team Leaders to see who is currently clocked in/not clocked in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just using `replace` function ?

```
var str = "<your>xml    </your>"
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); // Keep only one space character
str = str.replace(/>\s*/g, '>');  // Remove space after >
str = str.replace(/\s*</g, '<');  // Remove space before <
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERGVa/1/).

Finally, what you want is trimming a string and replacing multiple spaces with only one space :

```
function trimMyNode(str){
   str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); // Keep only one space character
   str = str.trim();
   return str;
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  document.write("<table border='0'>");
  document.write("<tr><td id=pic><img src=../images/employees/");
  document.write(trimMyNode(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
  document.write(".png width=100 height=100></td><td id=Yes>");
  document.write(trimMyNode(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

Here is another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VzV4/).

Comment: How will `<name>BOBBY                LEE              </name>` work?

Comment: One last question. As i am using getElementsByTagName("name"), where/how do i use the replace function in relation to that function call?

Comment: var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

Sorry - forgot to add that part.

Comment: Added that information to the Edit. I still need to know how to the remove the sapces, i'm just not sure where to use the replace code that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using jQuery** to make the call, why not try something like this within your ajax call:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim());
```

The ajax call should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'data.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(response) {
        $(response).find('employee').each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim());
        }
        // ... return final item
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I've not looked at using jQuery yet as I've been able to handle everything (so far) using just normal javascript. jQuery is something i could look at thohg - thanks.