# Remove unwanted whitespaces between tags in XML (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, xml

I receive an XML formatted as follows.

```
<rec>
      <id> servicedescription </id>
      <name> Description Value </name>
      <type> textbox </type>
</rec>
```

But this won't work since my system doesn't accept the spaces present between the tags. I require something as follows

```
<rec>
      <id>servicedescription</id>
      <name>Description Value</name>
      <type>textbox</type>
</rec>
```

Please help me out in Javascript. Thanks a lot

PS : Extremely sorry if this question has been asked before. I searched quite a lot but didn't get the info.

Comment: how you process this XML in javascript?

Comment: I receive a DOM object which has the XML. I serialize it into String format, convert it into JSON and process it.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346243/how-do-i-remove-unwanted-spaces-from-exported-xml-data-being-loaded-into-javascr?rq=1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following code should do the work (http://jsfiddle.net/b8FBn/):

```
var str = "<rec> <id> servicedescription </id> <name> Description Value </name> <type> textbox </type></rec>";
str = str.replace(/>\s*/g, '>');  // Replace "> " with ">"
str = str.replace(/\s*</g, '<');  // Replace "< " with "<"

alert(str);
```